# What is "primitive interface method" in Java?

Tags: java

I'm reading "Effective Java", here is a quote from this book:

> The interface defines the type, perhaps providing some default methods, while the skeletal implementation class implements the remaining non-primitive interface methods atop the primitive interface methods. Extending a skeletal implementation takes most of the work out of implementing an interface. This is the *Template Method* pattern.

The author is talking about some abstract classes like `AbstractCollection`, `AbstractSet`, etc, which implement an interface and provide some basic implementations. However, I don't know what `non-primitive interface methods` and `primitive interface methods` mentioned in the quote are. I know "primitive types" in Java, but what is "primitive methods"?

Comment: "primitive" means something that doesn't directly refer to algorihm or behavior, but is required to be implemented to make other functionality work. In case of `AbstractList` such are `get(int)` and `set(i, E)`---upon these two is built all other functionality of `List`, including complicated `indexOf`, `addAll`, `equals` etc (these methods are "templated" in skeletal implementation, giving name for the pattern).

Comment: I'd have to read that section in the book again, but since Bloch is talking about `Collection` classes, he might referring to the fact that generics can't accept a primitive type.  Only class-types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this context, a "primitive method" doesn't have anything to do with primitive types -- the meaning of "primitive" is different here.  According to ["Method Properties in Java" (p. 3)](https://riehle.org/computer-science/industry/2000/jr-2000-method-properties.pdf), a primitive method performs a basic task that doesn't rely on any other method to help do its work.

> A *primitive method* is a method that carries out one specific task, usually by directly referring to the fields of the object. It does not rely on any (non-primitive) methods of the class that defines the primitive method.

This is opposed to a "composed method" that relies on calling other methods to perform subtasks.  It appears that a primitive method performs tasks that are not or should not be broken down into smaller subtasks represented by other methods.

As an example, you may have a `Time` class that has hours and minutes.  Primitive methods may be individual setters for each of the hour and minutes fields, e.g. `setHour` and `setMinutes`.  A composed method, e.g. `setTime`, may call `setHour` and `setMinutes` to do its work.

The template method pattern involves creating a composed method that defines the order and structure of a workflow of tasks to be done, calling other methods that may be primitive.  With the advent of `default` methods in Java 8, it is possible for these methods to be in interfaces.